# RunReportRequest on more than 1 GA4 property

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics-4

I'm just a beginner with Python and I'm trying to run a .py script which runs a report on Google Analytics 4.

In order to do this I'm using the gapands4 module, and using the script below:

```
import gapandas4 as gp

service_account = 'client_secrets.json'
property_id = 'xxxxxxxxx'

report_request = gp.RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[
        gp.Dimension(name="country"),
        gp.Dimension(name="city")
    ],
    metrics=[
        gp.Metric(name="activeUsers")
    ],
    date_ranges=[gp.DateRange(start_date="2022-06-01", end_date="2022-06-01")],
)

df = gp.query(service_account, report_request, report_type="report")
print(df.head())
```

From this repository --> [/practical-data-science > gapandas4](https://github.com/practical-data-science/gapandas4)

By running it on a single GA4 Property I'm having no problem.

When I try to run it on more then one property through a for loop like this example:
[image: this]

it returns only the data of the second `property_id`.

Can someone help me on this?